# Excel custom functions work in Excel Desktop 2016, but fail in Excel Online

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel

We have tried endlessly to get custom functions to work in Excel Online (through multiple browsers) and are completely stumped.

**What is working**

1. All environments (local, dev, prod) work flawlessly in Excel Desktop 2016
2. All web environments fail with the message "There was an issue installing custom functions in this add-in. Please try to install this add-in again.

**What we have tried so far:**

1. Tried to load files from the server, still had the same issue
2. Reverted all changes back to when custom functions were working great. Verified on local and dev
3. Disabled web security in Chrome. CORS issues go away, but still getting a "There was an error in loading custom functions" message. Makes me think it is deeper than CORS.
4. I am able to successfully load custom functions from the Starcount tutorial. I'm using the exact same webpack configuration for the custom functions files

Open to suggestions on how to rectify this issue, as it is preventing us from re-submitting.

Comment: HI John, sorry to hear you're hitting an issue. can you specify what your CORS is for your CustomFunctions.json file? Likewise, can you share what F12 tools to see if there are any console errors in the browser?

Comment: Hey Keyur - Thanks so much for the quick response. Is there any way I could get in contact with you directly? May be able to troubleshoot quicker.

Comment: Thanks John for the call today and helping us find this issue, best of luck with your add-in!

Answer (score 0):

We found the cause, team is following up on a better error message. Excel for Web, has a bug if the manifest must not contain a 4 part version number for the function to load (note in Desktop the add-in will work correctly).

CUSTOM FUNCTIONS WILL FAIL ON EXCEL for Web:

```xml
<version>1.0.10</version>
```

CUSTOM FUNCTIONS WILL WORK if the versoin in the manifest is like this:

```xml
<version>1.0.0.0</version>
```